# Use jQuery to scroll up and down to div id

Tags: jquery, html

jQuery noob here. I have a fixed nav bar where I have an About div that I want to click on to scroll to the about section of the page. It's halfway working right now. If I am above the about section, clicking on the div will successfully scroll down to the about section, but if I choose to scroll past the about section it will not scroll back up to it if I click on the button. I am unsure about how to get it to scroll back up instead of only being able to go in one direction.

Here's my HTML:

```
<nav>
  <div id="about-button">About</div>
  <div id="projects-button">Projects</div>
</nav>

<section class="about-me">
  <div class="about" id="about">
    <div class="about-box"><h1>About</h1></div>
      <div class="bio-box">
        <h3>Bio</h3>
        <p class="bio-text">Bio text yada yada.</p>
        <p class="bio-text">More bio text yada yada</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="projects-section">
  <div class="projects" id="projects">
     <div class="project-main"><h1>Projects</h1></div>
       <a class="project-link" href="">
         <div class="project-picture"></div>
       </a>
     <div class="project-title">Project Name</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
function scrollToSection() {
 $("#about-button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top
    }, 2000);
 });
}
```

Comment: need to see your CSS too. would be helpful if you created a demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty of adding some basic CSS and longer dummy text for visual purposes based on your comments. Both buttons are working correctly now.

Changes I made to your original code:

- Removed the `scrollToSection()` function wrapper. Instead `$("#about-button")` is inside the `$(document).ready()` function. DOM element click handlers usually belong here so they are active only after the page finishes loading. If you wanted, you could refactor the function call to take `"#about-button"` and `"#about"` as parameters to a `scrollToSection()` function.
- Added a `"#projects-button"` click handler since it helps to complete the example.
- Removed extraneous `</div>` closure before each `</section>` closure. You already have a `</div>` right after the `</h1>` closure.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#about-button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });
  $("#projects-button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#projects").offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

nav>div {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

section {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div id="about-button">About</div>
  <div id="projects-button">Projects</div>
</nav>

<section class="about-me">
  <div class="about" id="about">
    <div class="about-box">
      <h1>About</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="bio-box">
      <h3>Bio</h3>
      <p class="bio-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin tempor, metus eu finibus commodo, dui nisl ullamcorper nibh, sit amet venenatis quam nisl id metus. Integer tempor urna diam, a sollicitudin ex pellentesque sit amet. In hac habitasse platea
        dictumst. Integer eget aliquet lacus, ut volutpat tortor. Maecenas sit amet dignissim tellus. Quisque magna velit, maximus sed feugiat ac, imperdiet vitae risus. Duis vitae faucibus nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent porttitor augue id felis
        molestie, eu pulvinar velit sollicitudin. Vestibulum at iaculis nulla. Maecenas semper, urna ut pharetra semper, felis quam pharetra orci, eu luctus ipsum velit egestas eros. Aliquam dui justo, volutpat id mi sit amet, finibus tincidunt turpis.
        Suspendisse gravida a lorem eget interdum. Curabitur laoreet, ipsum quis faucibus iaculis, odio massa tincidunt ante, non hendrerit lacus dolor ut elit.
      </p>
      <p class="bio-text">
        Praesent scelerisque elit sit amet pretium rhoncus. Cras sagittis ex a nunc consectetur, eget congue felis imperdiet. Proin varius interdum nibh et auctor. Donec pharetra eget arcu non ultrices. Phasellus lacinia ultrices risus vel tincidunt. Vestibulum
        vitae erat ligula. Aliquam vestibulum volutpat felis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris purus libero, fermentum sit amet quam sit amet, aliquam facilisis erat. Sed fermentum arcu diam.
        Proin iaculis commodo mi eget pharetra.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="projects-section">
  <div class="projects" id="projects">
    <div class="project-main">
      <h1>Projects</h1>
    </div>
    <a class="project-link" href="">
      <div class="project-picture"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="project-title">
      Morbi posuere id urna quis vestibulum. Proin semper dignissim nisi. Proin ut lectus ac est aliquam blandit vitae ut justo. Praesent fermentum lorem diam, pharetra tristique risus dapibus et. Fusce id urna arcu. Donec sit amet nulla laoreet neque congue
      placerat. Integer pretium laoreet ipsum ut sagittis. Aliquam feugiat volutpat arcu ac varius. Suspendisse a lorem ut justo sodales scelerisque elementum sed ligula. Donec ac porttitor lorem, et venenatis ipsum. Proin ut felis in augue consectetur
      dignissim quis vel dolor.
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

In case you really want to refactor scrolling to a function:

- The DOM click handlers are still initialized from `$(document).ready()`
- I'm assuming the section name is intentionally consistent for the button and the target. Otherwise, you'll need to pass separate string parameters for the button id and target id.

```js
function scrollToSection(section) {
  $("#" + section + "-button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#" + section).offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  scrollToSection("about");
  scrollToSection("projects");
});
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

nav>div {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

section {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div id="about-button">About</div>
  <div id="projects-button">Projects</div>
</nav>

<section class="about-me">
  <div class="about" id="about">
    <div class="about-box">
      <h1>About</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="bio-box">
      <h3>Bio</h3>
      <p class="bio-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin tempor, metus eu finibus commodo, dui nisl ullamcorper nibh, sit amet venenatis quam nisl id metus. Integer tempor urna diam, a sollicitudin ex pellentesque sit amet. In hac habitasse platea
        dictumst. Integer eget aliquet lacus, ut volutpat tortor. Maecenas sit amet dignissim tellus. Quisque magna velit, maximus sed feugiat ac, imperdiet vitae risus. Duis vitae faucibus nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent porttitor augue id felis
        molestie, eu pulvinar velit sollicitudin. Vestibulum at iaculis nulla. Maecenas semper, urna ut pharetra semper, felis quam pharetra orci, eu luctus ipsum velit egestas eros. Aliquam dui justo, volutpat id mi sit amet, finibus tincidunt turpis.
        Suspendisse gravida a lorem eget interdum. Curabitur laoreet, ipsum quis faucibus iaculis, odio massa tincidunt ante, non hendrerit lacus dolor ut elit.
      </p>
      <p class="bio-text">
        Praesent scelerisque elit sit amet pretium rhoncus. Cras sagittis ex a nunc consectetur, eget congue felis imperdiet. Proin varius interdum nibh et auctor. Donec pharetra eget arcu non ultrices. Phasellus lacinia ultrices risus vel tincidunt. Vestibulum
        vitae erat ligula. Aliquam vestibulum volutpat felis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris purus libero, fermentum sit amet quam sit amet, aliquam facilisis erat. Sed fermentum arcu diam.
        Proin iaculis commodo mi eget pharetra.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="projects-section">
  <div class="projects" id="projects">
    <div class="project-main">
      <h1>Projects</h1>
    </div>
    <a class="project-link" href="">
      <div class="project-picture"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="project-title">
      Morbi posuere id urna quis vestibulum. Proin semper dignissim nisi. Proin ut lectus ac est aliquam blandit vitae ut justo. Praesent fermentum lorem diam, pharetra tristique risus dapibus et. Fusce id urna arcu. Donec sit amet nulla laoreet neque congue
      placerat. Integer pretium laoreet ipsum ut sagittis. Aliquam feugiat volutpat arcu ac varius. Suspendisse a lorem ut justo sodales scelerisque elementum sed ligula. Donec ac porttitor lorem, et venenatis ipsum. Proin ut felis in augue consectetur
      dignissim quis vel dolor.
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Glad to help. Note that all the trouble with this solution is only worth it if you want the smooth scrolling effect going up or down. Otherwise @Anthony has the way simpler and more accessible solution.

Comment: For sure. Anthony's response didn't go unnoticed, but I do want the smooth scrolling effect and I also want to be able to control the speed, which this allows me to do.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need to use jQuery or JS.**

Changing your `nav` elements to actual links should work.

```
<div id="about-button">About</div>
<div id="projects-button">Projects</div>
```

The code above should become...

```
<a href='#about'>About</a>
<a href='#projects'>Projects</a>
```

The `a` elements use the `id` values of your desired destination as their ultimate destinations.